# Django if logic in template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-2.0

Is something like this possible in a template?

```
{% if request.path == url 'posts:post_detail' pk=instance.id %}
```

If not, how can I achieve this result being `True`? I want to this to be true when user is looking at a specific post such as `post/1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can using the [`as var`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#url) syntax:

```
{% url 'posts:post_detail' pk=instance.id as the_url %}
...
{% if request.path == the_url %}
...do something
{% endif %}
```